# How to deploy ASP.NET Core Web API with connectionstring to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to ASP.NET Core.  I am trying to develop a simple ASP.NET Core Web API. The API connects to the database server in the cloud. I stored the connection string in the `appsettings.json`, deployed the API to my local IIS, and ran the service. It worked fine. When I try to move the connection string to the environment variables and deploy again, the Web API does not work. The browser shows me "The page isn't working. HTTP error 500".

I have couple of questions to ask:

1. In a real world application, where should we store the connection string and deploy to the server since the user name and password is sensitive?
2. What's wrong with my Web API, since it wont work when the connection string is stored in the environment variables?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to temporarily enable `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` on the server so that you can get a more specific error message. Alternatively, you _may_ be able to get exception details from your cloud host’s logs.

Comment: What cloud hosting service are you using? That may impact the recommended location for storing your secrets.

Comment: I deploy the API in my local machine IIS.  The database is sit in the AWS.  It's work fine when the connectionstring is in appsetting.json while in Environment variable, it not work.

Comment: Ah, I see that now regarding your localhost. I apologize for missing that previously. Regardless, enabling `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` in your `Startup` class should provide you with a more specific exception message which will aid in isolating the issue.

Comment: I try to run the web API in visual studio, when hit the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Connection"), it give me an error message "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: connectionString' ".  What's means?  In my Environment Variable, i set the key as ConnectionStrings : Connection.

Comment: ASP.NET Core will actually fall back to environment variables using normal configuration methods, so you needn’t explicitly use `GetEnvironmentVariable()`. You can instead just use the standard e.g. `Configuration.GetConnectionString("key")`. This has the benefit of working with _both_ `appsettings.json` _and_ your environment variables (along with a few additional sources). Be aware that not all environments support colons in their environment variables, so you _may_ need to replace them with a `__`, which is a special convention the configuration provider supports for encoding the colons.

Comment: Since you are using Amazon AWS, one option for storing your production connection string is to store it in **AWS Secrets Manager**, which has an **ASP.NET Core** API for retrieving secrets. Alternatively, you could also store it in the **AWS Systems Manager**, which has the advantage of supporting an **ASP.NET Core** configuration provider, thus allowing you to use the same `Configuration.GetConnectionString()` method to retrieve your connection string.

Comment: I try Configuration.GetConnectionString("key") but it gave the same error message

Comment: AWS Secret Manager?  How to use it?  Do you have any tutorial link show how to do it?  I have try use the User Secret in Visual Studio, but it's not work.  Same error message.

Comment: Did you try swapping out the colon with an `__`? E.g., `connectionstrings__key`? (Assuming “key” is the name of your connection string.)

Comment: i try connectionString_Connection, connectionString__Connection, ConnectionStrings_Connection, ConnectionStrings__Connection,    connectionStrings_Connection, connectionStrings__Connection but still the same.

Comment: I try to restart the Visual Studio after change the Environment variable, and run again the Web API using visual studio, it work fine in the IIS run with Visual studio.  When I deploy to IIS server, run the web api from IIS Manager, it won't work.  Back to the square

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

In Program.cs

```
WebHost
.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(
    (hostingContext, builder) =>
    {
        var environment = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
        //codes... 
    })
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build()
.Run();
```

and your file names should be like appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json, ...

I answer your first question: If you want protect your username and password

1. You should use third-party applications (like consul)
2. You hash your configuration file. But this method does not make
   sense.
3. You do write and use hard code. But not change except deploy.

Comment: May I know what the purpose of those file  appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Staging.json?

Comment: These files configure the system according to the state of the environment. For example if you work development mode, the system uses appsettings.Development.json and appsttings.json files. (see more Continuous Integration)

Comment: My Environment variable is set to development.  If I want add connection string to json file, which one I should add to?

Comment: If your connection string change in a different environment, you should write this to environment-specific config.

Comment: I add connectionstring in appsettings.json while the environment set to development.  It still able to connect to database.  It's true my setting?

Comment: Yes, that's true. If you write connection string to appsettings.json, all environments use this connection string. But If you write connection string to appsettings.development.json, only the development environment uses this. (This theory is valid for my written code in answer)

Comment: ".AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)" this code import json file to project.

Comment: this code will import appsettings.development.json into project?  If without this code, the appsettings.development.json file will not include, right?

Comment: Yes, that's true.